# Problems configuring <on-connect> in icecast.xml

Tags: icecast

I have defined the following mountpoint in the icecast.xml project:

```xml
<mount type="normal">
<mount-name>/data.ogg</mount-name>
.....
   <on-connect>sh /bin/stream-start.sh</on-connect> 
</mount>
```

And defined a stream.sh script in `/bin/stream-start.sh`.

It is supposed that when `http://..../data.ogg` request is executed the stream-start.sh must be executed but is not executed. I have now the following questions:

1. How must the on-connect script be defined (/bin/stream-start or /bin/stream-start.sh)
2. how can you pass parameters to the starting script.

Answer (score 1):

In general you'll find it helpful to examine the Icecast logs. Both `access.log` *and* `error.log` may contain important information. Also it might be helpful to adjust `loglevel` up and restart Icecast for it to take effect.
https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/config-file.html#log

> #### on-connect
>
> State a program that is run when the **source** is started. It is *passed a parameter which is the name of the mountpoint* that is starting. The processing of the stream does not wait for the script to end.
>
> Caution should be exercised as there is a small chance of stream file descriptors being mixed up with script file descriptors, if the FD numbers go above 1024. This will be further addressed in the next Icecast release.
>
> This option is not available on Win32

(emphasis mine)

https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/config-file.html#mountsettings

Please also note that you *can not rely on 'the usual' environment variables of an interactive shell being present*, as e.g. PATH will not be populated. You might want to just `export >/tmp/on-connect-env.txt` from within the script and examine its contents to get an idea what you'll work with. Also you can not pass the interpreter as part of the command like you did above, you *must* put the interpreter with its full path in the shebang (`#!`) on the first line of the script.

Comment: Maybe it's usefull the ability to pass the connected user ip as parameter.